# Difference between `--all` and `--ignore-removal`

Tags: git

I get this message when I run `git add .`.

```
warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
Paths like 'config/.deploy.rb.swp' that are
removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.

* 'git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>', which is the current default,
  ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

* 'git add --all <pathspec>' will let you also record the removals.

Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.
```

I see default behavior of Git 2.0 will change `--ignore-removal` to `--all`.
But I'm not sure what is the difference of them. I want to have some example to understand it.

If I understand the description correctly, I don't need to use `git-rm` to remove a file from repository if I use `git add --all .`. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's easy to test:

```
$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/git/.git/

$ touch foo.txt

$ touch bar

$ touch bar.txt

$ git add .

$ git commit
[master (root-commit) dae701b] Add files.
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar
 create mode 100644 bar.txt
 create mode 100644 foo.txt
```

Okay. I've got a repository with 3 files: `bar`, `bar.txt`, and `foo.txt`. But maybe I didn't mean to add `bar`. Let's delete it.

```
$ rm bar

$ git add --all .

$ git commit
[master 070fb0e] Deleted mistakenly added file.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 bar
```

As you can see, `git add --all .` caused my file deletion to get staged.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls
a
$ touch b
$ ls
a  b
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        b

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ rm a    
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    a

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        b

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git add . --ignore-removal
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   b

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    a

$ git add . --all
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    a
        new file:   b
```

But if you use `git rm filename`, it will Remove files from the working tree and from the index, and add this change to commit:

```
$ ls
a
$ git rm a
rm 'a'
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    a
```

summary:

```
git add --all . stages all(changed, new, deleted)
git add . stages new and modified, without deleted
```